# Hangfire in WebApi with Autofac: Job not running

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, autofac, hangfire

I use Hangfire with the `Hangfire.MemoryStorage` in my WebApi Application.

I configured Hangfire in my owin `startup.cs`:

```
 Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage();
 app.UseHangfireServer();
```

And I try to use the job activation in a controller

```
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule(
                    () => ForceMissionEmail(mission.Guid),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

The code runs without error but the `ForceMissionEmail` method is not called after 10 seconds.

Comment: Try using Enqueue method on the IBackgroundJobClient to test is Hangfire is setup properly.

Comment: enqueue doesn't throw an error but my method wasn't called
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => ForceMissionEmail(mission.Guid));

Comment: I think you should try adding a console logger http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring-logging.html?highlight=log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Hangfire.Autofac Nuget package and the following lines of code resolves my problem

```
IContainer container = AutoFacConfig.Register(config, app);
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(container);
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage();
app.UseHangfireServer();
```